# Why do the tkinter windows open when the program runs and not when the buttons are pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a journal using tkinter. I have used different scripts for each part of the journal (main menu, morning entry and evening entry). I have set it so that the windows for morning and evening entry only open when their respective buttons are pressed on the main menu and this works well but when I run the programs both windows open automatically without me pressing anything. This happens before the main menu window is even opened. I have checked through the code and not noticed anything that can be causing this. Below is my code for the main menu and for the morning menu (evening is the same as morning menu with variables changed).

Main Menu

```
#importing libraries
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from Morning import *
from Evening import *

def StartUp():
    Start = tk.Tk()

    #Start Window Title and Size
    Start.title("Journal")
    Start.geometry("600x500")
    Start["bg"] = "white"
    #header Box
    header = Label(Start, text = "Journal",
                    height = 1,
                    width = 7,
                    font = ("Comic Sans", 16, "bold"),
                    bg = "white")
    header.pack(side = TOP)

    #Buttons
    morning_button = Button(Start, height = 2,
                            width = 20,
                            text = "Morning",
                            bg = "white",
                            command = lambda : morningwindow(),
    )
    morning_button.pack(side = LEFT)

    evening_button = Button(Start, height = 2,
                            width = 20,
                            text = "Evening",
                            bg = "white",
                            command = lambda : eveningwindow())
    evening_button.pack(side = RIGHT)

    wklyQs_button = Button(Start, height = 2,
                            width = 30,
                            text = "Weekly Questions",
                            bg = "white")
    wklyQs_button.pack()

    mnthlycheck_button = Button(Start, height = 2,
                            width = 30,
                            text = "Monthly Check In",
                            bg = "white")
    mnthlycheck_button.pack()

    quit_button = Button(Start, height = 2,
                            width = 20,
                            text = "QUIT",
                            bg = "white",
                            command = quit)
    quit_button.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    #mainloop
    Start.mainloop()


StartUp()
```

Morning Entry

```
#importing libraries
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from datetime import *

def morningwindow():
    Morning = tk.Tk()

    #Morning Window Title and Size
    Morning.title("Morning")
    Morning.geometry("1400x700")
    Morning["bg"] = "#97e8fc"

    #header Box
    header = Label(Morning, text = "Morning Entry",
                    height = 1,
                    width = 20,
                    font = ("Comic Sans", 16, "bold"),
                    bg = "white")
    header.pack(anchor=N)

    #date Box
    today = date.today()
    format_date = "Today's date", today.strftime("%b-%d-%y")
    date_text = Label(Morning, text = (format_date),
                 height = 1,
                 width = 20,
                 font = ("Comic Sans", 16, "bold"),
                 bg = "white"
                 )
    date_text.pack(anchor=NE, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
##Entries

    #Grateful Entry

    grateful_text = Text(Morning, height = 4, width = 160)
    grateful_text.insert(END,
                "What are you grateful for? \n1.\n2.\n3.")
    grateful_text.pack()


    #Good Day Entry
    goodday_text = Text(Morning, height = 4, width = 160)
    goodday_text.insert(END,
                "This is how I'll make today great:")
    goodday_text.pack(pady = 10)

    #Positive Affirmation Entry
    affirm_text = Text(Morning, height = 4, width = 160)
    affirm_text.insert(END,
                "Positive Affirmation \n")
    affirm_text.pack()

##Buttons

    #back Button
    back_button = Button(Morning, height = 2,
                        width = 20,
                        text = "BACK",
                        bg = "white",
                        command = lambda : Morning.destroy())
    back_button.pack(side = BOTTOM)

    #Submit Button
    submit_button = Button(Morning, height = 2,
                        width = 20,
                        text = "SUBMIT",
                        bg = "white",
                        )
    submit_button.pack(side = BOTTOM, pady = 10)

    #mainloop
    Morning.mainloop()
```

Comment: can't reproduce nor does it seem like the issue should exist. how you have described it seems that you call those functions in the files where you define them, so importing those files cause the functions to be run (because importing runs the file). Also don't use multiple `Tk` instances, if you want additional windows use `Toplevel`, also there should be only one `mainloop`. Also don't use `*` when importing, especially because you already have imported `tkinter as tk`

Comment: Do you know any way that I could import the files or integrate them into my main file in a way that wouldn't run them besides just simply adding them to one larger file?

Comment: there is no way, importing runs the file, in that file you can use `if __name__ == '__main__':` and put any code that you don't want to be run when importing under it or just don't call anything in that file, only define some names, but as I said, the given code you have provided in the question works as it should, window only opens when clicking the button